# How to change view of unclicked items of Recyclerview on clicking its item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am displaying a RecyclerView where I want to show a Tick mark on clicking on specific item. This tick mark should only be visible on selected item that if I select another item ,it should be show tick mark and another tick on previous item should be Gone. Its like getting a single select functionality on recyclerview. I tried to achieve this but tick mark is visible on every item I am selecting . I want it only to be visible on currently selected item.
Thanks in advance. I hope anyone of you would have solution to my problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter create a variable which will store clicked item

when a click is registered , store the position in the variable.

```
clickedItem = position;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In the bind view holder of the recycler view , for each item check

```
if(position == clickedItem){
   //Show tick mark
  }
else 
{
   //Hide tick mark
 }
```